# How to unparent a mesh within a mesh?

Tags: mesh

I want to unparent the hair that is attached to my body mesh. I want to make the hair its own separate mesh, but i'm not sure how to unparent it and to make it a separate mesh. I try to do the alt+p and it just unparents the whole mesh instead of just the hair.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing several things in my opinion: mesh, object, parents...

An object can be made of several meshes. If you want to make 2 meshes from one, select an edge of your mesh and rip (V key). If you want to separate a mesh and make it a new object, then press <kbd>P</kbd> (Separate).

Parent is a completely different thing, you can parent an object to another one, you can't parent a mesh to another mesh or to an object, a mesh is just part of an object or of another one.